Another Gambler's Ruin Problem
Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = -1) = 1/2.$$ Define $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ for $n \geq 1$ and $S_0 = 0$.
We can easily show that $$\mathbb{P}(S_n = N \text{ before } S_n = -1) = \frac{1}{N+1}.$$ The strategy is defining the function $f:\{-1, ..., N\} \to [0, 1]$ by the rule $$f(a) = \mathbb{P}(S_n+a = N \text{ before } S_n+a=-1).$$ One can show that $$f(a) = \frac12f(a-1) + \frac12 f(a+1),$$ and thus $$f(a) = \frac{a+1}{N+1}.$$ I would like to show that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n = -1\}\right) = 1.$$ Can I do this using my work above? The only luck I have is using the fact that $1 = f(a-1) + f(N-a)$.

$\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb{P}}$
Let $T$ be the event that $(S_n)$ never hits $-1$, so that
$$\PP\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n=-1\}\right)=1-\PP(T)$$
For $N\geq 0$, let $A_N$ be the event that $(S_n)$ hits $N$ before $-1$, $B_N$ the event that it hits $-1$ before $N$, and $C_N$ the event that it never hits either. Then
$$\PP(T)=\PP(T|A_N)\PP(A_N)+\PP(T|B_N)\PP(B_N)+\PP(T|C_N)\PP(C_N)$$
One can show that $\PP(C_N)=0$. (Actually, this can be done using your identity $1=f(a-1)+f(N-a)$ evaluated at $a=1$, which says that the probabilities of $A_n$ and $B_n$ sum to 1).
If $B_N$ occurs, then $(S_n)$ hits $-1$ and thus $T$ cannot occur. So $\PP(T|B_N)=0$. So
$$\PP(T|A_N)\PP(A_N)+\PP(T|B_N)\PP(B_N)+\PP(T|C_N)\PP(C_N)= \PP(T|A_n)\PP(A_n)\leq \PP(A_n)$$
If we define $f_N$ to be the same as your definition with $N$ specified, then
$$\PP(A_N)=f_N(0)$$
Then
$$\PP(T)\leq \lim_{N\to\infty}\PP(A_N)=\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(0)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N+1}=0$$
Thus $\PP(T)=0$ and
$$\PP\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n=-1\}\right)=1$$
